# a gettime() function that returns a uint16_t value in C

Tags: c, time.h, gettime, uint16

Hi I'm trying to do a `getTime()` function that returns `uint16_t` in C.

I do can successfully get an array of chars now

Here's my code for a output of array of chars.

Say today is `Dec 9 2014` the output will be `091214`

So how can i make the output a `uint16_t` type?

in this case can i keep the `"0"` in `091214` if it's a `uint16_t` type?

```
char *getT(){
struct tm *tm;
time_t t;
static char str_date[10];

t = time(NULL);
tm = localtime(&t);

strftime(str_date, sizeof(str_date), "%d%m%y", tm);
return str_date;}
```

and there's another approach i modified from the code i found on-line.

this one returns the sum of `9+12+14`....

```
uint16_t getD(){
struct tm *tm_time;
time_t ti;
//const time_t create_time;
uint16_t t, d;
ti = time(NULL);
tm_time = localtime(&ti);
t = (tm_time->tm_sec >> 1) + (tm_time->tm_min << 5) + (tm_time->tm_hour << 11);
d = (tm_time->tm_mday>>1) + ((tm_time->tm_mon+1) << 5) + ((tm_time->tm_year-80) << 9);
printf("%d %d %d %d \n",d,tm_time->tm_mday>>1,tm_time->tm_mon<<5,(tm_time->tm_year-80)<<9);
return d;}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you need this for and how you plan to use it?  Seems like it might be a bit of an XY problem.

Comment: So this is part of my assignment which is to get a time stamp for a file. And as instructor defined in the `struct` file the `creation_time` is `uint16_t`. My plan is `entry.creation_time = getTime(); ` That's why i want the return value of getTime() be uint16_t. Thanks.

Comment: Bits 0–4: Day of month, valid value range 1-31 inclusive.
Bits 5–8: Month of year, 1 = January, valid value range 1–12 inclusive.
Bits 9–15: Count of years from 1980, valid value range 0– = 127 inclusive (1980–2107).    and this is the requirement for the time stamp. Hope I didn't get uint16_t wrong...

Comment: Pick an "epoch date", then just use the number of days since that start date.  Gives you a range of about 180 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uint16_t getD() {
  time_t ti;
  ti = time(NULL);
  struct tm tm_time;
  tm_time = *localtime(&ti);

  //const time_t create_time;
  uint16_t t, d;
  d = tm_time.tm_mday
      + (tm_time.tm_mon + 1) * 32
      + (tm_time.tm_year - (1980-1900)) * 512;

  // Print ddmmyy
  printf("%02d%02d%02d\n", 
      (int) d%32, (int) (d/32)%16, (int) ((d/512)%128 + (1980-1900))%100);
  return d;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help the code works. Just one thing I need to know. The d it returned prints out 17801 but it actually represents 091214 in uin16_t. Is this the correct way to understand it?

Comment: @Shanji Yes  `17801 (base 10)` -- > `100010110001001 base 2` --> `100010 1100 01001 base 2`  --> `34 12 9 (base 10)` --> 2014 Dec 9.